# Android manifest not getting merged from android test flavor

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I have two flavors in build.gradle

```
 productFlavors {
  flavor {
     ...
  }

  anotherflavor {
     ...
  }
}
```

The folder structure looks like this:

- src/flavor/AndroidManifest.xml
- src/androidTestFlavor/AndroidManifest.xml
- src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml
- ...

When I build `flavor`, manifest (1) and (3) are getting merged. But not (2).

Is it possible to merge (2)? Should I specify anything explicitly?

Comment: please refer this link - > https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips.html

Comment: @KrunalKapadiya The link doesn't seem to be useful.

Comment: https://github.com/krunal3kapadiya/Gradle-Best-Practice use this demo

Comment: @KrunalKapadiya This is not useful either

Comment: What are you trying to do? have multiple test builds?

Comment: @UsualSuspect, facing the same issue, any luck?

Comment: @UsualSuspect I would think about creating a third ```buildType``` in `build.gradle`, say for example "staging" which contains the `AndroidManifest.xml` to add the permission needed for testing.

Comment: Or even better, just place the same `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `debug` sourceSet. Either way, for `release` build that permission will not be included.